# Angular routing based on http call

Tags: angular

Normally I use this kind of routing to load my components in app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '', component: HomeComponent
},
{
path: 'product-list', component: ProductListComponent
},
{
path: 'product', component: ProductComponent
}
];
```

But, I would like to base the routing on a http call to determine what component to load

For a example, I want to be able to have these URL's:

/nike

/nike-airmax

The first URL should load a product list page, and the second a product page

I have a http call to get the page type, it looks like this:

```
this.http.get(domain + 'api/ApiRoute?url=' + this.activatedRoute
```

(returns a int value, but it can return whatever I need)

### Problem 1

I don't know how to call a service (that returns the type) from app-routing-module.ts

### Problem 2

I don't know how to use the "type" from the service to determine the routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to do with Angular built in routing as its configuration should be static. the best thing you can do is create your own `SwitchComponent` on a `path: ':productName'`, where you will be able to render one of your required components with `*ngIf`s.

```
 ngOnInit(){
   this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
     switchMap((params) => this.myService.getComponentType(params['productName']))
   ).subscribe(type => this.componentType = type);
 }

.....
<product *ngIf="componentType == 'product'"></product>
<product-list *ngIf="componentType == 'product-list'"></product-list>
```

Comment: You are correct it's difficult to do with angular because of the static nature of routing, but I believe it is possible. One way to achieve it could be to have a lazy route that actually retrieves an entire NG module from a static url that actually serve different modules based on server-side logic.  Admittedly, this would be rather awkward and probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: even if you interfere into angular bundling and setup correct hashing logic on the backend you won't be able to navigate between paths. in case you've already downloaded ProductModule on a path /backendGeneratedModule you will no longer be able to open ProductListModule because angular will think the path is already "cached"

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think of that, You're absolutely right.

Comment: Thank you @AluanHaddad, I hoped I wouldn't have to go that way, but it works :)

Comment: @Marcus did you mean to address your comment to @Andrei?